# Change properties to a specific button from JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

What I want to do is be able to change the text, style, and parameters of the property (onclick(status, id, starttime, endtime)) by clicking. without having to refresh the entire table. just that specific button. So far I haven't been able to change any of that. My code below. Can't even change the text inside the specific button.

```
function cambiarEstado(estado, id, desde, hasta){
        var data = 'estado='+estado+'&id='+id+'&desde='+desde+'&hasta='+hasta;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/cambiar_estado.php",
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
             beforeSend: function(objeto){
                //$("#resultados").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
              },
            success: function(datos){
                document.getElementById("resumen_semanal").innerHTML = "$"+datos[1];
                document.getElementById("resumen_semanal_p").innerHTML = "$"+datos[2];
                console.log($("#tabla_resumen tr td #btn_stat"+datos[0]));
                $("#tabla_resumen tr td #btn_stat"+datos[0]).text("xyz");
            }
        });
    }

$consulta = "UPDATE facturas SET estado_factura = '$nuevo_estado' WHERE id_factura = '$id'";
$accion = mysqli_query($con, $consulta);
if($accion){
    $consulta_new = "SELECT id_factura, numero_factura, fecha_factura, nombre_cliente,firstname,lastname, total_venta, 
    estado_factura FROM facturas INNER JOIN clientes ON facturas.id_cliente = clientes.id_cliente INNER JOIN users ON 
    facturas.id_vendedor = users.user_id WHERE fecha_factura >= '$desde' AND fecha_factura <= '$hasta'";
    $accion_new = mysqli_query($con, $consulta_new);
    if($accion_new){
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($accion_new)){
    if($fila['estado_factura'] == 1){
        $total_resumen += $fila['total_venta'];
    }else if ($fila['estado_factura'] == 2) {
        $total_resumen_p += $fila['total_venta'];
    }
}$arr = [$id,round($total_resumen, 2),round($total_resumen_p,2)];
echo json_encode($arr);//json response
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: If we assume your JSON/PHP works as expected can you please click edit and then `[<>]' stacksnippet and make a [mcve] with just HTML and JS. Your animated gif is completely not understandable

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone, I'm not used to SOverflow. but i can solve it.
Changing attr onclick property with their params. What I really wanted to do is a two-state button (toggle) that in turn through ajax consult me ​​data. let below what i've done.

onclick function.

```
function cambiarEstado(estado, id, desde, hasta){
        var data = 'estado='+estado+'&id='+id+'&desde='+desde+'&hasta='+hasta;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/cambiar_estado.php",
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
             beforeSend: function(objeto){
                //$("#resultados").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
              },
            success: function(datos){
                document.getElementById("resumen_semanal").innerHTML = "$"+datos[2];
                document.getElementById("resumen_semanal_p").innerHTML = "$"+datos[3];
                console.log($("#tabla_resumen tr td #btn_stat"+datos[1]));
                if(datos[0] == 1){
                    $("#tabla_resumen #btn_stat"+datos[1]).text("Pagado");
                    $("#tabla_resumen #btn_stat"+datos[1]).removeClass("btn btn-sm btn-warning");
                    $("#tabla_resumen #btn_stat"+datos[1]).addClass("btn btn-sm btn-success");
                    $("#tabla_resumen #btn_stat"+datos[1]).removeAttr("onclick");
                    $("#tabla_resumen #btn_stat"+datos[1]).attr('onclick','cambiarEstado('+datos[0]+','+datos[1]+', '+desde+', '+hasta+')');
                }else if(datos[0] == 2){
                    $("#tabla_resumen #btn_stat"+datos[1]).text("Pendiente");
                    $("#tabla_resumen #btn_stat"+datos[1]).removeClass("btn btn-sm btn-success");
                    $("#tabla_resumen #btn_stat"+datos[1]).addClass("btn btn-sm btn-warning");
                    $("#tabla_resumen #btn_stat"+datos[1]).removeAttr("onclick");
                    $("#tabla_resumen #btn_stat"+datos[1]).attr('onclick','cambiarEstado('+datos[0]+','+datos[1]+', '+desde+', '+hasta+')');
                }
                //$("#resultados").html(datos);
            }
        });
    }
```

PHP BACKEND

```
$consulta = "UPDATE facturas SET estado_factura = '$nuevo_estado' WHERE id_factura = '$id'";
$accion = mysqli_query($con, $consulta);
if($accion){
    $consulta_new = "SELECT id_factura, numero_factura, fecha_factura, nombre_cliente,firstname,lastname, total_venta, 
    estado_factura FROM facturas INNER JOIN clientes ON facturas.id_cliente = clientes.id_cliente INNER JOIN users ON 
    facturas.id_vendedor = users.user_id WHERE fecha_factura >= '$desde' AND fecha_factura <= '$hasta'";
    $accion_new = mysqli_query($con, $consulta_new);
    if($accion_new){
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($accion_new)){
    if($fila['estado_factura'] == 1){
        $total_resumen += $fila['total_venta'];
    }else if ($fila['estado_factura'] == 2) {
        $total_resumen_p += $fila['total_venta'];
    }
}$arr = [$nuevo_estado,$id,round($total_resumen, 2),round($total_resumen_p,2)];
echo json_encode($arr);//json response
    }
}
```

FIRST TABLE OF THE QUERY (to mysql table)

```
    $desde = strtotime($_POST['resumen_desde']);
$hasta = strtotime($_POST['resumen_hasta']);
$resumen_desde = $_POST['resumen_desde'].' 00:00:00';
$resumen_hasta = $_POST['resumen_hasta'].' 23:59:00';

$total_resumen = 0;//contador de pagos
$total_resumen_p = 0;

//$consulta = "SELECT * FROM facturas WHERE fecha_factura >= '$resumen_desde' AND fecha_factura <= '$resumen_hasta'";
if(!empty($resumen_desde) and !empty($resumen_hasta)){
    $consulta = "SELECT id_factura, numero_factura, fecha_factura, nombre_cliente,firstname,lastname, total_venta, estado_factura FROM facturas INNER JOIN clientes ON facturas.id_cliente = clientes.id_cliente INNER JOIN users ON facturas.id_vendedor = users.user_id WHERE fecha_factura >= '$resumen_desde' AND fecha_factura <= '$resumen_hasta'";    
}
if($resumen_desde == ' 00:00:00' or $resumen_hasta == ' 23:59:00'){//$resumen_desde == '00:00:00' and $resumen_hasta == '00:00:00'
    $consulta = "SELECT id_factura, numero_factura, fecha_factura, nombre_cliente,firstname,lastname, total_venta, estado_factura FROM facturas INNER JOIN clientes ON facturas.id_cliente = clientes.id_cliente INNER JOIN users ON facturas.id_vendedor = users.user_id";
}//echo $resumen_desde.$resumen_hasta;
$accion = mysqli_query($con, $consulta);
echo '<div class="table-responsive outer_div_inner"><table class="table table-striped" id="tabla_resumen"><tr><th>ID</th>
<th>N° COMP</th>
<th>FECHA COMP</th>
<th>CLIENTE</th>
<th>VENDEDOR</th>
<th>TOTAL VENTA</th>
<th>ESTADO</th></tr>';
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($accion)){
    if($fila['estado_factura'] == 1){
        $estado = '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="btn_stat'.$fila['id_factura'].'" onclick="cambiarEstado('.$fila['estado_factura'].','.$fila['id_factura'].','.$desde.','.$hasta.')">Pagado</button>';
        $total_resumen += $fila['total_venta'];
    }else if ($fila['estado_factura'] == 2) {
        $estado = '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" id="btn_stat'.$fila['id_factura'].'" onclick="cambiarEstado('.$fila['estado_factura'].','.$fila['id_factura'].','.$desde.','.$hasta.')">Pendiente</button>';
        $total_resumen_p += $fila['total_venta'];
    }
    //$total_resumen += $fila['total_venta'];
    echo '<tr><td>'.$fila['id_factura'].'</td>
        <td>'.$fila['numero_factura'].'</td>
        <td>'.$fila['fecha_factura'].'</td>
        <td>'.$fila['nombre_cliente'].'</td>
        <td>'.$fila['firstname'].' '.$fila['lastname'].'</td>
        <td>'.$fila['total_venta'].'</td>
        <td>'.$estado.'</td></tr>';
}echo '</table></div><span id="total_resumen_srv">'.$total_resumen.'</span><span id="total_resumen_srv_p">'.$total_resumen_p.'</span>';
?>
```

if I am not very clear I can record a video.